# 404 when pulling a private Docker repo from Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Today I deployed a few new servers, and ran into a strange issue. On one of our private hub repos, I suddenly got a 404. It's strange, since it has worked fine in the past. Moreover, all of the other (private) repos under the same account works fine.

```
root@some-server:~# docker pull foo/bar
Pulling repository foo/bar
1112f98a0e3d: Error pulling image (latest) from foo/bar, HTTP code 404
511136ea3c5a: Download complete
2758ea31b20b: Error pulling dependent layers
2014/08/23 12:59:58 Error pulling image (latest) from foo/bar, HTTP code 404
```

The dockercfg is in place, and works fine for the other repos

```
root@some-server:~# cat ~/.dockercfg
{"https://index.docker.io/v1/":{"auth":"abc123","email":"docker-deploy@foobar.net"}}
```

I've also triple checked the to make sure that the group the account ('docker-deploy@foobar.net') has read write to this particular repo.

My gut feeling tells me that it is something on Docker's end.

What makes it even more strange is that I can pull the same repo without any issues from another account.

Comment: The issue is reported here btw: http://status.docker.com/

Answer (score 0):

Closing this issue, as it is an issue reported on Docker's status page, and hence an issue upstream on Docker's end.